# How to do ensembling in machine learning and deep learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-networks

I am trying to do text classification. I have 3 `logistic regression` models, 2 `recurrent neural net` model, and 2 `convolution neural network` models. I want to take ensemble of all these.
What I have done is averaged the prediction of all these 7 models.

Is this a correct approach?

or should I first set a threshold and then take mod of all these 7 models

Answer (score 0):

You should pad (increment, i.e., +1) rows/columns of a confusion matrix based on class votes and ground truth (truth table) coming from each classifier and CV fold used.  Then, use "ensemble weighted majority voting" (EWMV) or, "classifier fusion".

Also, your question has nothing to do with Python or Keras, since it applies to any platforms/software used.