# Is 1 - (10-fold cross validation error) the same as 10-fold CV accuracy?

Tags: cross-validation, accuracy

If I compute misclassification error by 10-fold cross validation in context of binary classification task, does it make sense to say that 1 - this error is the accuracy estimated by 10-fold cross validation?

Answer (score 0):

Error is usually minimized for a classifier via gradient descent, like mean square error or cross-entropy error, etc.  On the other hand, SVM and cascade correlation neural networks are solved via gradient ascent.  CV accuracy is one metric that can be used to reflect performance.  Basically, if error is low, accuracy is typically high.

Comment: that is true, but not the answer to my question though. With what I mentioned I am evaluating performance of bayesian optimization. I just need to know whether 1 - (missclassif.error estimated by 10-fold CV) is the same as accuracy estimated by 10-fold CV.

Comment: That should work, since it's okay to average error (accuracy).  I was gonna say accuracy is 1-error, but it depends and you have to be careful about terminology.

Comment: You should calculate accuracy however, and not just use 1-error.   See the answer here on use of the confusion matrix (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451826/how-to-do-ensembling-in-machine-learning-and-deep-learning)

Comment: If I am calculating 1-error while I am using missclassification error, i.e. zero-one loss, is it the same as calculating accuracy ?

Comment: Error is typically based on minimization (maximization) of an objective function, which is not classification error.

Comment: I am using 1- misclassification error (or zero-one loss or whatever name) as an objective function for an optimization, namely bayesian optimization for hyperparameter search in training a binary classifier. I just want to know, whether I can report it as accuracy. Normally it would be accuracy (because accuracy = 1- missclassification error) but does this hold also if I estimate this misclassification error by 10-fold cross validation?